# Do parallel streams have their own copies of local variables?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have to iterate over a collection of several million items and do this up to a few hundred times.  I'm seeing big performance increases with parallel streams.

The code I have inside the for loop can run on it's own safely provided it gets its own copy of any variables declared in the loop.

So my question is, do loops inside a parallel stream get their own copy of variables declared inside the loop?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your question. You have a lambda that is passed as argument to `parallelStream(...)`. Within the lambda, there is a loop. Within the loop, you create variables. Is this correct?

Comment: post the relavent code, so that we can understand your situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas can use - inside its body - only "final" or "effectively final" variables, which are declared outside the lambda body. This means, that these variables cannot be changed after initialization anymore. Thus it does not matter if the threads "share" the same variable or use a copy of it.

Comment: One thing to note is that if the variable itself holds a reference to a mutable data structure, then any thread can modify the underlying data structure. For example a Map or List

Comment: Yes, of course. This problem arises always when working with threads, it has nothing to do with lambdas.

Comment: We have a formal term for that, [*effectively final*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4-500). You should use that instead of “quasi final”.